# transparent proxy (SSL error)

Tags: networking, iptables, squid

Right now we are having transparent proxy in our network environment.

we have been set proxy settings to  browsers in all systems.

While accessing the https sites in browsers no issue  but few of the developers having an issue while downloading repository files from command prompt or in eclipse console they got the errors related to 
ssl errors in eclipse and command-prompt.

My Transparent proxy configuration as link as follows

http://www.purplealienplanet.com/node/25

Please help me to come out of issue

Comment: That guide and config has no special provisions for HTTPS and is only a transparent proxy for plain HTTP. Any HTTPS issues must have a different cause, not related to your proxy.

Comment: What proxy settings did you use on your PCs' browsers? (Please update the question with these details.)

Answer (score 1):

Transparent proxying is a little involved when it comes to HTTPS. I know squid supports a MITM setup that should work - they call it SSL bump. It is possible to do this without MITM but I don't think squid supports this yet. Various commercial web filters do.

Comment: Commercial web filters do nothing more than SNI filtering (looking into hostname client browser adds to its SSL hello-handshake). It is perfectly possible to do the same in Squid 3.5+.

Comment: Thanks - I've been a bit lax in keeping up with squid developments in that area, largely because I work on a web filter, and we do that bit, and don't need squid to :) You're absolutely correct of course in the method - between the two of us, I suspect we have answered the question!